# Defining a ViewModel for a razor partial that will either display a form if only one and a table if multiple

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to create a Partial View with MVC that will either show a List of items if more than one or an html form if only one.

Should I create a ViewModel specifically for this partial that has the following:

```
public Product Product { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<Product> Product { get; set; }
```

Or would I be better off just sending the list. If I just send the list will I be able to bind the first (and only) item to the form?

The goal is to bind the single product properties to the form if only one and if multiple loop through them and output in an html table.

Comment: I don't see a problem with this approach. I would prefer to rename the properties to `ProductToEdit` and `ProductList` to be more readable :)

Comment: What is the problem exactly?! your method or your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems simpler to me if the model contains a single property -- call it `Products` since it's a collection. In the view, test its `Count()` and either render the form or the table. Binding won't be a problem -- just take the `First()` item if the `Count() == 1`.

If you have two properties, what will you do if they both have data? What if the product in the single-value property is different from the first one in the collection? Which one wins?

You can solve these problems by enforcing business rules in the controller or on the model itself -- but yuo can avoid them entirely if you just have a collection.

Comment: thanks for this response. I was confused because I wasn't sure if I would be able to bind a list to a partial and then in the partial be able to get the first item in the list and use it to bind the form in the partial. Please confirm that this is possible.

Comment: actually yes, this is my problem. So I have the razor if statement setup but within the form how do I bind the asp.net tag helpers like asp-for="FirstItem.Id", asp-for="FirstItem.Name" and so on. It is forcing me to use the main page model which is IEnumerable.

Comment: I think I got it. I need to do asp-for="First().Name". Make sense?

Comment: @BlakeRivell Sorry, was super-busy yesterday. I haven't used the tag helpers, so I don't know specifically, but it looks like `asp-for="First().Name"` should work. Alternately, store a reference to the first item in a local variable, and then refer to that variable directly, something like `@{ var firstItem = Model.First(); }` and then later `asp-for="firstItem.Name"`